# How to connect with SQL Server with PHP and XAMPP?

Tags: php, sql-server, xampp, runtime-error

I'm using XAMMP (WINDOWS 10) and getting the error:

**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()**

I've inserted the following rows in the php

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_73_nts_x86
extension=php_sqlsrv_73_nts_x86
```

And downloaded the SQL PHP Drivers from the Microsoft website and pasted it on *C:\xampp\php\ext*

Comment: which operating system you are using ?

Comment: operating system:  Windows 10

Comment: have you tried wampp, it is specifically for the windows os